# Reformat comma separated values to table with Google Spreadsheet

Tags: json, excel, google-sheets

I need to get a bunch of values from a JSON file into a Google Spreadsheet. I followed [these](https://medium.com/@paulgambill/how-to-import-json-data-into-google-spreadsheets-in-less-than-5-minutes-a3fede1a014a) instructions and I'm able to read my JSON file hosted in my Dropbox.

Now the problem is that the data ends up like this:

```
value1,1,value2,2,value3,3
```

I want visualize the values with the Spreadsheet Charts but as far as I know that's not possible if the data is only available like that.

I couldn't figure out a way to reformat these comma separated values and display them in a table like that:

```
value1 | 1
value2 | 2
value3 | 3
```

Any idea how I should proceed there?

Edit: I found the split function, which brings me a bit closer to my goal but that's about it.

It'll transform the input into:

> value 1 | 1 | value2 | 2 | value3 | 3

Comment: Because there's a lot of overlapping functions and if you find one way to do it with generic spreadsheet tools which are available in both apps it'll be "cross platform" if you want to call it that.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work in Google Sheets, and assumes the string is in A1.

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^(.+?),"),SPLIT(A1,","),ROW(OFFSET(A1,,,COUNTA(SPLIT(A1,","))/2,1))*2-{1,0},0))`

Note: the third A1 (the one directly after the OFFSET function) must be A1, or any cell in row 1. It is to generate row numbers for the formula to process, and not directly related to the string at all.